# Como mostrar uma DIV e ocultar outras com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

queria ajuda com esse código. Eu fiz  e funciona, mas queria enxugar isso porque está muito verboso e horroroso. Sou iniciante em javascript. As aspas simples são porque o codigo vai dentro de um ECHO do PHP.
OBS: não quero fazer com jQuery.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

```js
function filtro(){
    getValue = document.getElementById('selecao').value;
    if(getValue == ''){
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(getValue == 'ano_grau'){
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(getValue == 'curso'){
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(getValue == 'cargo'){
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(getValue == 'avaliacao'){
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(getValue == 'disponibilidade'){
        document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'block';
    }
    
}
```

```html
    <select id='selecao' onChange='filtro()'>
    <option value='' selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
    <option value='ano_grau'>Ano em que colou grau</option>
    <option value='curso'>Curso realizado depois de formado</option>
    <option value='cargo'>Cargo atual</option>
    <option value='avaliacao'>Avaliação entre a formação e a exigência do cargo</option>
    <option value='disponibilidade'>Disponibilidade de colaboração com a faculdade por meio de entrevistas e palestras</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Seu código acima parece estar incompleto...

Comment: eu coloquei o HTML só pra mostrar que se trata de um select. Quero mesmo é enxugar o javascript.

Comment: Sem o código completo não vou conseguir te ajudar, senão vou ter que chutar uma resposta.

Comment: Sempre que postar uma pergunta, é importante explicar a dificuldade encontrada e fornecer sempre um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2):

Bom, cada um tem um estilo, eu primeiramente iniciava todos os elementos para `display = none` e conforme a escolhe na caixa de seleção pego o mesmo valor e manda mostrar com o mesmo nome da `div`, ***exemplo***:

```js
function init() {
  document.getElementById('ano_grau').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('curso').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('cargo').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('avaliacao').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('disponibilidade').style.display = 'none';
}

function filtro() {
  init();
  const getValue = document.getElementById('selecao').value;  
  if (getValue) {
    document.getElementById(getValue).style.display = 'block';
  }
}

(function() {
  filtro();
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <select id='selecao' onChange='filtro()'>
    <option value='' selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
    <option value='ano_grau'>Ano em que colou grau</option>
    <option value='curso'>Curso realizado depois de formado</option>
    <option value='cargo'>Cargo atual</option>
    <option value='avaliacao'>Avaliação entre a formação e a exigência do cargo</option>
    <option value='disponibilidade'>Disponibilidade de colaboração com a faculdade por meio de entrevistas e palestras</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="margin: 5px">
  <div id="ano_grau">Ano Grau</div>
  <div id="curso">Curso</div>
  <div id="cargo">Cargo</div>
  <div id="avaliacao">Avaliação</div>
  <div id="disponibilidade">Disponibilidade</div>
</div>
```

Se tivesse o `HTML`, talvez possa diminuir mais o código, mas, acredito que esse ficou bem claro como proceder com otimização, leitura de código e manutenção que posteriormente possam acontecer.